# Limit of number of files when we using multi upload in js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, multi-upload

I'm using JS for multiple upload
Now i want to know 
Is there any limit for choosing  files when we upload files using JS.
i got sucked browser and system as well when i try.
please provide details.

Comment: No, YOU please provide details :/

Comment: You got sucked? Sounds like this is off-topic...

Comment: I'm crated a multi upload js and try to upload 100 files at the same time it's create some html part also in div according to number of files
the total number of size is only 38 MB
witch is not issue i thing.

when i upload only 50 files browser got stacked.

Comment: Code? Framework? Spell checker?

Answer (score 1):

try to use dropzone plugin its very efficeint and nice plugin for uploading files and it also gives option for parallelUploads